# Create new data frame based on list of column from list

Tags: python, python-3.x

Consider a list with 2 values as shown below.

```
list_1 = ["Col1", "Col2"]
```

I have another data frame df which contains below value and has same column name i.e. Col1, Col2, Col3.

```
Data frame = df
|Col1   | Col2   | Col3   |
|-------|--------|--------|
|1      |6.      |11.     |
|2.     |7.      |12.     |
|3.     |8.      |13.     |
|4.     |9.      |14.     |
|5.     |10.     |15.     |
```

I want to create a new data frame i.e. df_1 which should appear like this below:

Data Frame = df_1

| Col1 | Col2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 6. |
| 2. | 7. |
| 3. | 8. |
| 4. | 9. |
| 5. | 10. |

One approach to resolve this is using below code.

```
df_1 = df[["Col1", "Col2"]]
```

But the issue is that I have more than 100 variable in my list(list_1) and want to know if there is any another approach like looping technique which will make my script looks smaller

Comment: " create new data frame df_1 with above values using for loop..." It's not at all clear what you're asking. What are you trying to loop over? What are you doing inside that loop? What data are you trying to populate? Can you [edit] your question to show a sample of your expected output, and how it's different from your current output? Something like `df_1 = df[list1]`?

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use the list_1 to select the columns.

```
df_1 = df[list_1]
```